# mixing and matching mysql & mssql whileloop within an if case

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, if-statement

Please take a look at the following code and tell me if there is a way around it.

```
if ($current_server_is_mysql):
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS)) {
else:
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $RS, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
endif:
```

Depending on the server I'm working with, I'd like to compile my records into the $RS recordset the proper/native way. If I can get pass this part, the rest should be all right cause both mysql and mssql $row can be tapped into the same way. For example, `$row['fieldname']` will give me the field value whether the row was a mysql or mssql resource. So it all boils down to the above snippet failing.

The error I get points to the `else:` part in the above snippet.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in D:\Hosting\5291100\html\blueprint\pages\populate_migration_table.php on line 415
```

I can understand why I am getting this error.

But, I'm hoping you guys can offer a work-around it without me resorting to duplicate the entire while loop she-bang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some syntax mismatches, and putting your code in a function like this worked for me:

```
if ($current_server_is_mysql):
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS)) {
        ProcessThisRow($row);
    }
else:
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $RS, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        ProcessThisRow($row);
    }
endif;

function ProcessThisRow ($row) {
    /*Put your code in this function */
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Oops...I just realized what you're trying to accomplish with the brace left open.

Comment: VERY CLEVER. YOU ARE A SMART MAN!.